# javascript armstrong number test case errors

Tags: javascript, while-loop

The question I'm solving is:

> Write a javascript program which returns true when a given number is Armstrong number and false otherwise. Any n digit number is armstrong number if sum of nth power of each digit equals to the number itself. Example: `153` is a `3` digit armstrong number because sum of 3rd power of each digit equals to `153` (`153 = 1*1*1 + 5*5*5 + 3*3*3`).
>
> Hint: Use `Math.pow(i,n)` to calculate nth power of `i`. Use `parseInt(i)` to get integer value of `i`. Your output code should be in the format `console.log("Result is ", variableName)`

My code is:

```
var num = prompt("Enter a number to check Armstrong");
var t = "Armstrong";
var f = "Not Armstrong";

function armst(x) {
    var a = x, b, sum = 0;
    while (a > 0) {
        b = a % 10;
        sum += (b * b * b);
        a = parseInt(a / 10);
    }

    if (sum === x) {
        return t;
    } else {
        return f;
    }
}

var output = armst(num);
console.log("Result is : ", output);
```

When I run this code on the course website it gives correct outputs but doesn't pass all the test cases according to the compiler.

Am I missing something? What could be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting an [narcissistic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number)/Armstrong number, you need to take the length of the number as string as `n` for taking the power for summing the value.

Just a personal word, because of the specification, I would take [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), because you have already a number, instead of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
function armst(x) {
    var value = parseInt(x, 10),
        rest = value,
        digit,
        sum = 0,
        n = x.toString().length;       // add toString, if a number is entered

    while (rest) {
        digit = rest % 10;
        rest = Math.floor(rest / 10);
        sum += Math.pow(digit, n);    // use it here
    }

    return sum === value
        ? "Armstrong"
        : "Not Armstrong";
}


var num = prompt("Enter a number to check Armstrong"), // try with 54748
    output = armst(num);

console.log("Result is: ", output);
```

Comment: your 1st and 2nd edits provide correct outputs when I enter num=153 ,however it seems that the compiler goes into an infinite loop because the website does not display the message that the program is correct(it usually does) and my cpu is runnung at 100%.The 3rd edit does not work at all.

Comment: maybe you entered a number, then `toString` is required to get the length of the number.

Comment: 5474
547
54
5
Result is:
Not Armstrong     || this happens in case of 54748 in 5th edit after putting console.log(rest) in while loop.

Comment: in the latest edit, I'm getting the correct outputs.The website still says the code is incorrect but I think this is another issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think in some of the tests `b = a%10;` and `a = parseInt(a/10);` can give some rounding errors. I suggest using a different approach with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Something like this:

```
function isArmstrong(number){
  const digits = number.toString().split(''); // get all the digits
  const numberLength = digits.length; // get the length of the number
  const sum = digits.reduce((accumulator, digit)=> parseInt(accumulator)+Math.pow(parseInt(digit), numberLength))
  // use reduce to iterate and add every number to the numberLength power
  return sum === number
}
```